# Getting permissions of a user in SharePoint 2K3 List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-2003

I have been using SharePoint server 2003. I need to retrieve the list of permissions using `SPList.Permissions.Xml`. But I dont find the permissions given to the user anywhere in the Xml returned.

Say I have a user 'A' whose Login name comes as an attribute in the Xml. But the permissions (such as `View`, `View&Insert`, `View&Insert&Delete` etc.,).

I do not want the site level permissions as they can be retrieved using SPSite.Roles. I need to get the permissions of the `SPList` alone. Any help would definitely be appreciated (befittingly!! :) )

Note that I am using SP 2003 (Not SP2007 where RoleAssignments can be used to get these details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Once upon a time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_upon_a_time) I wrote a code like this:

```
SPDocumentLibrary source = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["source"];
SPDocumentLibrary target = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["target"];
foreach(SPPermission permission in source.Permissions)
{
    try
    {
        target.Permissions.Add(permission.Member, permission.PermissionMask);
    }
    catch { } // "ask rumen for info"
}
```

As it shows how to navigate in permissions collection and how to copy them, I hope it helps.